# CollapsingToolbarLayout inside parent fragment and child fragment tablayout with recyclerView are not scrolling together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a **parent fragment** with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with some layouts.

Then inside, there is a `TabLayout` with two **child fragments** having recycer-View both are not scrolling together.

when user scroll-up and scroll-down inside child recycler-View   **Parent fragment** **tabLayout** and **Child Fragment** **textView** (move up and down)/hide and show.

How to solve this issue?

Parent Fragment with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_speed_search_bar_rounded_rectangle"
        android:text="Search"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
              
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
             android:id="@+id/tab"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />

               
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar">

        </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Child Fragment 1&2 layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the scrolling behavior to the `ViewPager` so that the `CoordinatorLayout` is able to sync the scrolling of the `ViewPager` content (i.e., the `RecyclerView`) with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    ...>
```